# Вводя данные в программу, я нажимаю enter, но приходится вводить ещё символ, чтобы программа дальше выполняла работу

Tags: c

Я учу си по учебнику. Сижу на  linux mint. Компилятор gcc.

Сам вопрос :
Почему когда я начинаю вводить данные в программу (предположим что я ввожу:45.2, 48.3, Speed=23) мне нужно нажать enter потом ввести ещё символ и только тогда продолжиться выполнение программы. Зачем вводить ещё символ? Почему по первому нажатию клавиши enter программа сразу не выводит значения?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float lantitude;
    float longitude;
    char speed[80];
    puts ("Data:\n");
    while(scanf("%f, %f, %79[^\n]",&lantitude,&longitude,speed)==3);
        {
            printf("lantitude: %f, longitude: %f,info: %s", lantitude,longitude,speed); 
            puts(";\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно, как вы вводите данные. Покажите строку ввода.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(scanf("%f, %f, %79[^\n]",&lantitude,&longitude,speed)==3);
```

Т.е. пока вы будете вводить правильную строку (считывать 3 значения), это надо делать вновь и вновь (см. точку с запятой).

Когда наконец будет введено что-то неверно - можно перейти к выводу введенного...

Так?